# what are disadvantage of using angular elements

Tags: .net, angular, model-view-controller, angular-elements

Our application is build on .net MVC using cshtl view, we are planning to migrate it into angular. For this we want to use angular element so that it can be easily mixed with cshtml pages. We would like to know what will be advantage and disadvantages of using angular element in such case

We are using angular element with .net MVC page

Comment: The question is unclear. You don't need Angular Elements to create an Angular SPA that talks to a .NET API. ASP.NET Core has a [project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022) just for this. Are you looking for a way to use server-side rendering? Or mix both Angular and server-generated pages? You don't need Angular Elements for either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.